# convert row table to column in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a column chart that the user can insert a value in every year.

my table is look like this.

[image]

is there any possibility to view my table like this?

```
  |  Course   | 2013 | 2014 | 2015 |  // column name
  |  BSIT     | 657  | 453  | 424  |
  |  Education| 657  | 453  | 424  |
```

I want to view like that so that my column chart display look like this

[image]

I don't know if this question is possible to do. I wish...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If its limited to a small amount of years(not something like then 20 previous years) then it can be achieved with conditional aggregation like this:

```
SELECT Course,
       max(CASE WHEN year = 2013 then value end) as year_2013,
       max(CASE WHEN year = 2014 then value end) as year_2014,
       max(CASE WHEN year = 2015 then value end) as year_2015,
       .....More years if you need
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY Course
```

Comment: my chart have a selection tag which is my user can change the record in every year using ajax.  if the user select 2015 for example the chart display the record from 2015 to 2013 and if the user select 2016 the chart display from 2016 down to 2014. how to do a condition like that from sql?

Comment: Can't you filter it inside ajax? you can create this in a table with all possible years, and then filter those he selected

Comment: thank you for helping me. after a couple of trying and trying using your code I found that I can filter using ajax by changing the value of year next to CASE WHEN. thank you very much, your answer help me a lot #Yossi